# Uninstall upgrade 13.04

Tags: upgrade, 13.04

Can I uninstall the Ubuntu 13 upgrade?  It stopped about half way through the upgrade and now I get all kinds of nuisance errors.  Worst of all, the software center no longer functions, so I need to know how to do this through the terminal or some other way.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update update && sudo apt-get install -f && sudo dpkg --configure -a` This would install any missing dependency and reconfigure all your packages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no way to uninstall the upgrade. But you could succeed finishing the upgrade process by typing following via the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```